# Unable to put message in ibm mq using container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile, ibm-mq

I have two docker containers which I'm building using docker-compose. One of which initializes the ibm mqs and another is the one exposes rest end points(using SpringBoot project) to send message to the ibm mq which were set up by first container. When I get the docker-compose up I am getting the below error

```
mock-service_1  | 2020-01-29 08:07:52.928 ERROR 1 --- [nio-7090-exec-2] c.j.ids.controller.AcarsController       : JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
acars-mock-service_1  | com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'. Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').

mock-service_1  |         at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
```

I'm able to put the messages in the same queue if I run the SpringBoot application locally from my IDE without any error. Not sure what is the issue using separate containers. My DockerFile looks like this

```
FROM ibmcom/mq
USER root
RUN useradd ibm-mq -G mqm && \
    echo ibm-mq:passw0rd | chpasswd
USER mqm
COPY config.mqsc /etc/mqm/

EXPOSE 9443 1414
```

And config.mqsc

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  ibm-mq-mock:
    build: 
      context: ../mock-service/ibm-mq
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9443:9443
      - 1414:1414
    environment:
     LICENSE: accept
     MQ_QMGR_NAME: QM1 
  mock-service:
    build:
      context: ../mock-service
    ports:
      - 7090:7090
    depends_on:
     - ibm-mq-mock
    environment:
     MQ_QMGR_NAME: QM1
     CHANNEL: DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
     IBM_MQ_HOST: localhost
     IBM_MQ_PORT: 1414
     IBM_MQ_USERID: admin
     IBM_MQ_PASSWORD: passw0rd
     IBM_MQ_QUEUE: DEV.QUEUE.1
     LOG_LEVEL: INFO
     PROFILE: test
```

Comment: `reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE')` just means that you can't get to the hostname and port you specified over the network accessible to that "container".

Comment: i assume it is something to do with exposing of ports in the docker-compose.ybl file.  I'm unable to get the exact point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localhost inside your spring container, is your spring container. Instead of setting the host to localhost for your MQ Connection you need your container's / host ip.

How you do it depends on your host's platform, but it will be something like `host.docker.internal`

Using your docker-compose.yml, you should be able to set

```
IBM_MQ_HOST: ibm-mq-mock
```

Comment: thanks @chughts . I checked the ip of the container using   "docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' de3de72fdf6c"  and gave the ip in place of localhost and it worked.